# Contact form 7 WordPress plugin not showing last name on my email that I've received

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to set my contact form 7 to have the first and last name. But I cannot figure out how to set the last name.

The first name:

```
<label> First Name (required) [text* your-name] </label>
```

But what about the last name?

I've tried something like `your-last-name`, `last-name`, `default:user_last_name`, `your_last_name` etc.. but still have no luck.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your entire form instead of the single line?

Comment: @Daniel <pre><label> First Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label><code>

<pre><label> Last Name (required)
    [text* last-name] </label><code>

<pre><label> Email address (required)
    [email* your-email] </label><code>

Comment: So is the field not displaying at all or just not displaying in the layout that you'd like?

Comment: My problem is the email that I received is not showing the last name.@Daniel

Comment: @Daniel Thank you so much! I get it now, and it's working now!

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget that you can also set up an email to the person who's enquiring or signing up by clicking the Mail (2) checkbox at the bottom of the page and configuring that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your feedback, you need to update the "Mail" tab of the form to include any new field that you add. See the image below:

[image]

You can try the following in your Mail tab:

```
You have a new enquiry:

First Name: [your-name]
Last Name: [last-name]
Email Address: [your-email]
```

This will then show the values in the body of the email you receive. See the below example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please click the `'Mail'` tab just in the side of `'Form'` tab.

[image]
Find the `[last-name]` tag which you have written in the form `<label> Last Name (required) [text* last-name] </label>` and place that tag where you want to be displayed in the mail, as described in the image above.